# local.settings.json is not part of "publish" folder and deployment is unsuccessful

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-function-app-proxy

I created a Azure function using .net core 2.0 and core tools. It is a HttpTrigger function. I used

dotnet restore

dotnet publish -c Release

to create the publish files. 2 files and 2 folders I can see in my publish folder under bin/Release/.netcoreapp2.0. These are:

bin

myapi

host.json

namespace.myapi.deps.json

I deployed them on Function App on Azure under 'wwwroot' folder. I keep getting 404 error. Then I also copied local.settings.json file under 'wwwroot' folder and function app url access was a success.

My Query: Why local.settings.json was missing from publish folder? Any parameter missing in my dotnet commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that the only difference between 404 error and your function success was the absence of `local.settings.json`? I ask this because Azure Function App does not depend on or use that file anyhow.

`local.settings.json` file is only meant for running your functions locally using azure-functions-core-tools. Ideally, this file should never be published. More information about the file is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file). If you want to sync your local settings with the Azure function app, you can use the flag `--publish-local-settings` while publishing using azure-functions-core-tools. Or you can manually add those settings.

You should never have to publish that file.

Comment: I am using      dotnet publish -c Release --publish-local-settings command but seems this is not valid?

Comment: @MahHem apologies, that (--publish-local-settings) is applicable when publishing via `azure-functions-core-tools`. So, if you do `func azure functionapp publish <appname>`. I assumed you had `func` installed because of the presence of `local.settings.json`. Or, if you would rather not publish your app using that command and would still like to update settings, you could do `func azure functionapp publish <appname> --publish-settings-only`.